# How to mock Pusher with RSpec in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, pusher

Currently using Pusher and RSpec.

```
Pusher.should_receive( :trigger ).with( 'message', { :data => '12345' })
```

This would work, except the call is `Pusher[ 'channel-id' ].trigger...`

How to mock this with RSpec?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well `[]` is a function name so it can be stubbed.  In the Pusher source you see: `def_delegators :default_client, :webhook, :channel, :[]`  So all of these methods are forwarded to `default_client`.  So this is actually a chain of methods.

I would do what you want to do like this.

```
 mock_client = mock('client')
 Pusher.stub(:[]).with('channel-id').and_return(mock_client)
 mock_client.should_receive( :trigger ).with( 'message', { :data => '12345' })
```

I do not have rspec handy right now, but see no reason why it would not work.

Answer (score 7):

Newer versions of Pusher support a shallower API that is easier to stub:

```
expect(Pusher).to receive(:trigger).with("channel-id", "message", { data: "12345" })

Pusher.trigger("channel-id", "message", { data: "12345" })
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also [pusher-fake](https://github.com/tristandunn/pusher-fake/tree/master/lib/pusher-fake) which starts up a fake server for your tests, so you don't have to stub – it lets your app both send and receive via that fake server.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Papile's answer is essentially correct. Here's the code I used:

```
Pusher.stub_chain( :[] , :trigger )
Pusher[ channel_id ].should_receive( :trigger ).with( 'message',  { :data => '12345' })
```

Actually, it turns out this code does not work because it does not match `channel_id`.